# Conectando ElephantSQL com java

Tags: java, postgresql, conexão

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o [ElephantSQL](http://elephantsql.com) (postgres) através do java. Com o mesmo código eu já consegui fazer conexão ao postgres local (apenas mudando a url, user, password). Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
private static final String DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:postgres://nklbcxow:MINHA_SENHA_NO_ELEPHANTSQL@elmer.db.elephantsql.com:5432/nklbcxow";
private static final String USER = "nklbcxow";
private static final String PASS = "MINHA_SENHA_NO_ELEPHANTSQL";

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);

        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro na conexão", ex);
    }
}
```

Mas está um erro de Driver:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://nklbcxow:wjz0RtEbVnksKBJoaEp5uTnBP1gaMy8Y@elmer.db.elephantsql.com:5432/nklbcxow
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>       at ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:20)
>       at ProdutoDAO.registerTemp(ProdutoDAO.java:20)
>       at BDLearning.main(BDLearning.java:25)
>   C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)

Sendo que o próprio site, está indicando usar o driver que eu já estou usando : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que seja algum formato na url que eu não estou sabendo, eu tentei de algumas outras formas, mas nenhuma funciounou.

No site deles tem um doc que da um exemplo de como fazer em java, eu copiei o exemplo e continuou dando problema

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a sua URL de conexão não esteja correta. Tente isso:

Substitua `ENDERECO`, `PORTA`, `NOME_DO_BANCO`, `SEU_USUARIO` e `SUA_SENHA` pelos valores corretos.

```
private static final String DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:postgres://ENDERECO:PORTA/NOME_DO_BANCO";
private static final String USER = "SEU_USUARIO";
private static final String PASS = "SUA_SENHA";
```

Comment: Entao amigo, essa são as [informações](http://prntscr.com/gvreov) que o Elephant me fornece. A url que ele me passe tem um formato próprio

Comment: @Matheus talvez o seu .jar do driver do PostgreSQL não esteja configurado corretamente no seu classpath.

Comment: Como eu vejo isso ? Pq como eu disse antes, eu usei esse mesmo drive para conectar num PostgresSQL local.

Comment: E no PostgreSQL local deu certo? Você só trocou os parametros de conexão?

Comment: Sim, deu certo só trocando os parametros

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a pergunta tem quase 3 anos desde que foi feita, mas como passei por esse problema recentemente, e essa *thread* me ajudou, gostaria de auxiliar quem mais, por via das dúvidas, também quiser utilizar o ElequantSQL como banco de dados e integrar com o Java.

Como consta na documentação do ElequantSQL para Java (https://www.elephantsql.com/docs/java.html), o formato da URL deve ser o seguinte:

```
 String url = "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database";
```

Onde *host* é apenas a parte de fora dos parênteses do campo *Server*, localizado na aba *Details* da instância de banco criada. Ainda, **NÃO** deve ser utilizado o mesmo formato de URL indicado na aba *Details* do banco quando este for utilizado remotamente por alguma aplicação Java, e sim o apontado acima.

Por fim, apesar da resposta dada acima ter me auxiliado na conexão ao banco de dados PostgreSQL remoto da ElequantSQL, ela contém um pequeno equívoco em sua URL, que deve utilizar *postgresql*, e não *postgres*, em sua formatação, ficando assim a configuração padrão dos parâmetros passados ao método *getConnection()* da classe *DriverManager* ao conectar o app Java ao banco:

```
private static final String DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://ENDERECO:PORTA/NOME_DO_BANCO";
private static final String USER = "SEU_USUARIO";
private static final String PASS = "SUA_SENHA";

DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```